# How to return row id after copying row in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, pdo, last-insert-id

I need to copy/duplicate a row in my table and then return the new row's 'id' value.  My 'id' column is an auto-increment field.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_users;
                      CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_users
                          SELECT * FROM users 
                          WHERE user_id = $user_id
                      UPDATE tmp_users 
                          SET id = NULL;
                      INSERT INTO users 
                          SELECT * FROM tmp_users;
                      DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_users;");

$sth->execute();
```

If I do `$id_new = $dbh->lastInsertId();` this returns '0', but not sure why.  Any ideas?

Comment: [`PDO::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) does not seem to support multiple statements in one string; even if it did, you're missing a semicolon after your `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` statement so it would still turn out invalid.

Comment: The statements above seems to be executing just fine using prepare.  However, I cannot seem to return the id of the newly inserted row.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a syntax error in it, you're missing a semicolon at the end of your `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_users
    SELECT * FROM users 
    WHERE user_id = $user_id
UPDATE tmp_users 
    SET id = NULL;
```

Even though you're under the belief that the statement "executes just fine", you can plainly see that the above excerpt has *only one* semicolon at the end; i.e. it is *a single statement* with a syntax error in it, **not** two separate `CREATE` and `UPDATE` statements.

PDO seems to be handling multi-statement queries very poorly, failing to report errors in them. I have performed the following test:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('test1');
                      INVALID STATEMENT;
                      INSERT INTO test VALUES ('test2');");
$sth->execute();
```

As you can see, I have included an invalid statement between two valid `INSERT` statements. After I run the above code, my test table has only the `'test1'` value inserted, but the `'test2'` insert was not performed and no error was reported by PDO.

The syntax error in your `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` prevents the table from actually being created, which also prevents the rest of the statements from functioning correctly, thus you get no new row inserted into the `users` table and no last inserted ID.

**UPDATE:** Here is the actual [PHP bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61613) for this PDO behavior, apparently still unresolved.